# Cmvision colorgui not working?

Tags: ros, kinect, cmvision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi i am trying to use cmvision stack and have successfully installed and built the package. however, whenever i run the command to launch the colorgui, the gui launches but no image is displayed. upon clicking on the blank image it automatically closes and causes a segmentation error. i have tried to display the image using rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color and it is working ffine. help will be much apreciated

wh07@wh07-VM:~/fuerte_workspace/swri-ros-pkg2/cmvision$ rosrun cmvision colorgui image:= /camera/rgb/image_color
[ WARN] [1388044266.669792195]: couldn't register subscriber on topic []
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/113031/cmvision-colorgui-not-working?/) by [daidalos](https://answers.ros.org/users/10171/daidalos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-12-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you using Kinect?

How did you installed the CMVISION?

I use GROOVY of ROS, as I know the CMVISION is just for HYDRO version of ROS, so I changed the libraries of the CMVISION that I can use them in GROOVY maybe you could do that also?

---

Originally posted by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) with karma: 264 on 2014-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0